# Convert Gmail mail into file and send over a webservice

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

Is it possible to create an add-on that can send off the contents of an email into a webservice? I see lots of documentation on add-ons interacting with external webservices and have been able to follow a simple demo about it, but there isn't much I can find about interacting with the emails itself.

I have an add-on in Outlook that grabs the email and sends it off to a webservice, but I want to replicate this in Gmail in some way.

Next, I would also like to know if it's possible to use a different web service based on the user. For example, if I were to deploy this same add-on for a coworker but they needed to send the email to the different service. Is there a configuration file somewhere that controls this?

Lastly, I was also interested in how Gmail add-ons store personalized information, as I feel like it would help clear things up. E.g. how the tasks add-on grabs the right ones for the currently logged in user and where they are stored.

I would be open to any other solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Communicating with web service**

You can use the `UrlFetchApp` class to connect to any target web service if it can be accessed via HTTP request. If you need to access different web services for different users, you can either do so via storing "user:url" property (see below) or by conditionally changing the URL according to effective user.

**Determining the user**

You can determine under whose authority the Add-on is running by using a `Session` class method `getEffectiveUser()` and `getEmail()` on the resulting user.

**Storing personalized info**

As for storing and fetching personalized information, there is a `PropertiesService` class you can use. Since you want to store info related to end users, you'll need to get a `Properties` class instance with access to user-specific properties via `getUserProperties()` method.

**Useful links**

1. Gmail Add-ons [reference](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#gmail_add-ons);
2. `PropertiesService` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service);
3. [Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) on `PropertiesService` usage;
4. `UrlFetchApp` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app);

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to some good resources. Do you have any recommendations on changing the URL?e.g. I was thinking of either have a textbox card that asks for a web service URL if it does not exist for the user already before it actually goes into a menu that allows the body of the email to be sent towards a web service.

Comment: Glad I could help! Well, that's the same thing as with conditionally saving URLs to properties - use the `CardService` in general, as Gmail Add-ons Ui is constructed through it and its `TextInput` class to allow users to input data + `PropertiesService` to get (`getProperty()` method on store) and set (`setProperty()` method) URL's respectively. Other than that, there is really nothing special (except that you can't push a success state back to the add-on unless it is returned as an immediate response to HTTP request)

Comment: I was wondering about the syntax needed to be able to read from the TextInput, I only seem to find setter methods. I found a way to parse it into a JSON but I was wondering how do just get the string value.

Comment: @EricY, that's a part of general Gmail Add-on concepts, you need to take a look at [actions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/actions), specifically, at event object and its structure (input values are contained in `formInput` and `formInputs` parameter when an action is emitted)